# Android pusher Chatkit create user

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, pusher, chatkit

I've begun implementing pusher Chatkit to my first android App and am running into the problem of automatically creating users on the server for Chatkit. I've followed the getting [started page](https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/getting_started/android) where it tells me I can either go on to the console or I can run `npm create-environment.js`.

Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to do it manually?

I've searched on StackO and the pusher Chatkit website however I haven't found any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this is to use the Node.JS Server [here](https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/reference/server-node). Which in my case is used in conjunction with Firestore Cloud Functions.